# Passing lng/lat with extra bundle doesnt work

Tags: android, dictionary

i m creating a project with three main activities (lets call them Activity 1, 2 and 3).
In activity 1, i pass the number in my bundle extra.

```
newActivity.putExtra("LAT", getText(R.string.LAT1));
newActivity.putExtra("LNG", getText(R.string.LNG1));
```

then,in the 2nd one, i get this like:

```
     double Lata;
    double Lnga;

//in onCreate..
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        Lata = extras.getDouble("LAT");
        Lnga = extras.getDouble("LNG");
```

and then,i m passing them to the 3rd activity like this:

```
newActivity.putExtra("LAT",Lata);
newActivity.putExtra("LNG",Lnga);
```

Finally, in the 3rd activity:

```
public class mapview extends MapActivity
{
 @Override  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

 setContentView(R.layout.map);

 MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 //mapView.setSatellite(true);
 //mapView.setStreetView(true);
 List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
  Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);

 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
final double Latc = extras.getDouble("LAT");
 final double Lngc = extras.getDouble("LNG");
Integer txt_map = extras.getInt("MAP_NAME");





 TextView mapname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.museum_address_name);
 mapname.setText(getText(txt_map));

 Double lat = Double.valueOf(Latc*1E6);

    Double lng = Double.valueOf(Lngc*1E6);

    //---------------------------------------------------
    GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(Double.valueOf(Latc*1E6).intValue(), Double.valueOf(Lngc*1E6).intValue());
    MapController controller = mapView.getController();
        controller.setCenter(center);
    controller.setZoom(15);
    //---------------------------------------------------

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(), lng.intValue());
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");


 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
 }
 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
 {
 return false;
 }
}
```

The result is somewhere in South America,but my lat and long are in europe..What am i doing wrong?i m trying to fix it for more than 2 hours...:(

EDIT

```
04-25 23:58:19.001: W/KeyCharacterMap(3746): No keyboard for id 0
04-25 23:58:19.081: W/KeyCharacterMap(3746): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
04-25 23:58:22.461: W/Bundle(3746): Key LAT expected Double but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value 0.0 was returned.
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.os.Bundle.getDouble(Bundle.java:1017)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.os.Bundle.getDouble(Bundle.java:1000)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at kostas.menu.athensmuseums.museum_item.onCreate(museum_item.java:39)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 23:58:22.481: W/Bundle(3746): Key LNG expected Double but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value 0.0 was returned.
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.os.Bundle.getDouble(Bundle.java:1017)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.os.Bundle.getDouble(Bundle.java:1000)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at kostas.menu.athensmuseums.museum_item.onCreate(museum_item.java:40)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-25 23:58:22.491: W/Bundle(3746):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 23:58:24.251: W/MapActivity(3746): Recycling dispatcher com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@44ec4318
```

Comment: Are you actually attaching the bundle when starting the new activity?

Comment: getText(R.string.LAT1), what does this line do?

Comment: i have the lat in my string.xml file with the name LAT1

Comment: @Tony which is the new activity you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `getText` returns a `String` or a `CharSequence` so you're putting a string into the bundle but reading it as a double. Instead, make sure you convert it to a double first:

```
newActivity.putExtra("LAT", Double.parseDouble(getText(R.string.LAT1)));
newActivity.putExtra("LNG", Double.parseDouble(getText(R.string.LNG1)));
```

That's assuming you've already properly validated that your `TextView`s really contain a valid double.

Comment: PLEASE take a look at the warning i m getting..i have posted it in my answer!!thanks @kabuko

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear: "Key LNG expected Double but value was a java.lang.Integer". You put in an integer at some point.

Comment: may the problem be here?? GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(Double.valueOf(Latc*1E6).intValue(), Double.valueOf(Lngc*1E6).intValue());

Comment: Please read the actual stack trace and look there: at kostas.menu.athensmuseums.museum_item.onCreate(museum_item.java:40)
. You only included snippets so it's difficult for anyone else to know exactly what code is there.

Comment: line 40 is Lata = extras.getDouble("LAT");

Comment: So like I said, you're putting an integer into your bundle, and reading it out as a double. Look at where you use putExtra for the intent that you used to launch this activity.

Comment: Again, find where you're mistakenly putting the integer into your bundle and put in a double instead. Also, I'm not a mind reader. I can't help in detail if you don't make sure that the code you post here is relevant/what you're actually using.

Comment: put extra i m using there thst you told me to correct before..newActivity1.putExtra("LAT",Double.parseDouble((String) getText(R.string.theocharakis_LAT)));
     newActivity1.putExtra("LNG", Double.parseDouble((String) getText(R.string.theocharakis_LNG)));

Comment: may is a problem that i m using   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
?

Comment: i have restarted the app several times and i have no get the same warning again..is it possible the previous warning to be wrong?

Comment: It's possible you had an old version of the app installed and you replaced it with the fixed version.

Comment: If there was something wrong i would get the same warning more times,right?so as i m not getting the warning now,the problem is solved?